# How can I fix my Mac volume glitching?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, sound-volume

When I use my Mac, the volume glitches. Every few seconds, all the output devices disappear, even if it is only the 'Internal Speakers', and the volume mutes, then everything returns and the volume goes back to about 20%.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Volume Glitch]

I've also reset SMC and PRAM/NVRAM.

I have Windows (Boot Camp) on an external USB drive. The issue doesn't happen there. But, I can't boot into Windows using the selector tool (hold alt on startup), so instead, I need to boot into recovery mode and then select it as the startup disk. Normal macOS doesn't recognise the Windows drive either. This may be related to the issue.

I don't think it's a third-party app, but I used AppCleaner to uninstall all my audio utilities and my most recent installations.

Is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you haven't got rid of the leftovers from all that 3rd party stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug with Froyosoft's Sound Booster driver that started happening all of a sudden. Sound Booster installed a driver, so when AppCleaner deleted the app, it left the driver behind, which caused the problem. I found this out after looking through crash logs as suggested by @anki and some others on [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423547/) by me.

**Audio utilities can leave behind drivers. Completely uninstall the utilities and their drivers.**
To know if a certain utility has installed a driver on your computer, check your input and output devices for any devices with the name of the audio utility, e.g. Sound Booster.

I had to use their driver uninstaller from their website.

Comment: AppCleaner and similar products are vastly over-replied upon, IMO, and can delete the wrong file or miss files that it should have cleaned. Always use the app's uninstaller, if provided.