# How can you find out what caused a process to crash?

Tags: macos

There's a core process (`coreaudiod`), that's crashing repeatedly. How can I find what's killing it? (i.e. is it another process?, is it a bug?, is RAM or CPU full?)

Comment: If there's a crash, see ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

Comment: @anki Thanks to you, I've found 20 crash logs for `coreaudiod`. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: The log says: `Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY`. What does that mean?

Comment: The best you can do is look at the logs see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361608/151019 but that does look like a bug or bad memory or you have a Kernal extention that is incorrect

Comment: You can't diagnose a bad address to a released pointer as an end user. You need to find the extension that is causing it & remove it, update it, or ask the developer. I still think you've got 3rd party leftovers from your earlier question.

Comment: I went through the logs and found the crash threads. They all happened on the same line of code (I think that's what it is) from `com.froyosoft.SoundBoosterDriver`. It hadn't caused me a problem in the past, and I don't know what caused it to start crashing `coreaudio`. I uninstalled the app and the driver using their uninstaller, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: There ya go! I'm sure I mentioned that the very first time you posted the question, before you moved it to Ask Different ;))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crash logs can be found in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` or in Console app.

The team that has access to the full code base for the app in question ( Apple) is best situated to make sense of these crash reports:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/analyzing-a-crash-report

Depending on if the console app has some relevant errors logged and combined with how you are using the Mac when the process ends, you might have a chance to isolate what causes or contributes to this or have to [reverse engineer or work with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes) to analyze these files.